# Conversion from Access 2010 to 2007

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to use a database created with Access 2010 in 2007? I keep getting the "unrecognized format" error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What file format is it in? You might want to try saving it as a mdb if its in the new accdb format. To that that you go to save as and then select the format as access 2002 - 2003 database (from memory!)

EDIT:

Ok as it is an accdb file format your problem is that the 2010 accdb format is slightly different to the 2007 version due to the new access 2010 featues. Have a look here for what to do to sort it out

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/access/thread/33ad105c-b752-4f65-9913-32ea967171f4

Comment: It is 2007 format (it is the default format of 2010). I cannot save to mdb because there are multivalued fields and some other features not available in MDB :(

Comment: I have changed my answer in light of that info

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try that.

Comment: Are you integrating with Sharepoint? If not, then you really shouldn't be using multi-value fields, which are a terrible idea from just about any standpoint.